# $.ajax not working in Internet Explorer but works on other browser

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using $.ajax and it works fine in all the browser except Internet explorer

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.abc.com",
    data: { "entry_1734836994": qtya1},
    type: "POST"      
});
```

I am getting the data in all the browsers except IE.

I tried the console option to check the error

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.abc.com",
    data: { "entry_1734836994": qtya1},
    type: "POST",
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

this displays Log `[object Object]` in the console. I also added datatype as text but that also did not worked out.

Thanks

Comment: Is this going cross-domain?

Comment: What version of jquery are you using ? you need to use the v.1.10.0 to get compatibility with older browser like IE

Comment: What version of IE? IE<10 doesn't support CORS through the normal xhr, therefore you have to extend jquery to support IE's XDomainRequest object.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is a cross-domain request relying on CORS. IE8 and IE9 support [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/), but not through the usual `XMLHttpRequest` object that jQuery uses (instead they use the `XDomainRequest` object). (IE10 fixes that.) Unusually, jQuery doesn't smooth over this browser difference for you, you need to add a plugin to do it. Discussion and links in [this jQuery issue ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8283).